# [Xero][Quote] Can not store tracking category option for quote line item

Tags: xero-api

I have the issue when creating or updating the Quote. I can not set TrackingCategory options for line items. I request api like document but it not success.

The Tracking Category I have
[tracking category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJJS7.png)

Here is my expected:
[my expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyUv4.png)

Please help me
Thanks you
Here is format payload for lineItems

```
"LineItems": [
    {
      "AccountCode": "200",
      "Description": "Development work - developer onsite per day",
      "UnitAmount": 650.0000,
      "DiscountRate": 10.00,
      "LineAmount": 585.00,
      "ItemCode": "DevD",
      "Quantity": 1.0000,
      "TaxAmount": 58.50,
      "TaxType": "OUTPUT",
      "Tracking": [
        {
          "Name": "Location",
          "Option": "Foo Bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Do you get an error, or does it just not store the tracking information?

Comment: No error, Just not store tracking information,

Comment: Update: I work file on Invoice and PurchaseOrder, but Quote it's not work